# Is it possible to redirect to a new origin from within an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have something like:

```
<iframe src="https://foo.com"></iframe>
```

I'd like to https://foo.com to redirect to https://bar.com.

I've tried server-side redirects (https://foo.com returning a 302) and client-side redirects (foo.com contains a script which `window.location.href = https://bar.com`), but am thwarted cross-origin browser errors when sending post messages:

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://foo.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://bar.com').
```

Is redirection within an iframe possible?

Comment: What happens when you redirect?

Comment: Need to be more specific about what the post message errors are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can redirect.

It sounds like you are doing that successfully too.

… but if you redirect to a different origin then you are redirecting to a different origin. Any cross-origin requests will need permissions to be granted to the new origin.

Redirecting from `http://foo.com/` to `http://bar.com` does not give `bar.com` all the permissions granted to `foo.com`.

If you want to send a `postMessage` to `bar.com` then that the origin you need to mark the message as being intended for.